# URL without .html file extension + corresponding redirection + no trailing slashes

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

**Three independent scenarios:**

1. In the *www root directory* there is a file `foo.html` and there is no folder `foo`: `/foo.hmtl`
2. In the *www root directory* there is a folder `foo` in which the file `index.html` is located: `/foo/index.html`
3. In the *www root directory* there is a folder `foo` in which the file `bar.html` is located: `/foo/bar.html`

**The aim in all three cases is:**

The *canonical url* should be `example.org/foo`:

- `example.org/foo.html` should redirect to `example.org/foo`
- `example.org/foo/` should redirect to `example.org/foo`
- `example.org/foo//` should redirect to `example.org/foo`
- `example.org/foo/index.html` should redirect to `example.org/foo`
- `example.org/foo/bar.html` should redirect to `example.org/foo`

**My first approach for scenario #1:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule foo foo.html [NC,L]
```

Requesting `example.org/foo` returns the content of `/foo.html` but of course there is no redirection from `example.org/foo.html` to `example.org/foo`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule foo foo.html [NC,L]

Redirect 301 foo.html foo
```

Requesting `example.org/foo` or `example.org/foo.html` returns the HTTP status code *500 Internal Server Error*.

**My second approach for scenario #1:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule foo foo.html [R=301,NC,L]
```

Requesting `example.org/foo` redirects to `example.org/foo.html` and then returns the content of `/foo.html`.

...

I tried much more but never got the result I am looking for. So could someone please help me and explain it to me like I was three years old? ;-)

Comment: You wrote `there is no folder foo` but then contradicted yourself

Comment: Also if you want final URL to be `example.org/foo` then which file should it display: `/foo.html` or `/foo/index.html` or `/foo/bar.html`?

Comment: @anubhava, Hello sir, Even I was thinking the same thing but then I thought may be user needs to do like url `http://localhost:80/foo/index.html` to `http://llocalhost:80/foo` though this looks vice versa of rule of friendly url(in browser) to difficult url(backend redirect internal one) but as per OP's question I had written it like that :)

Comment: I wrote "Three **indepenent** scenarios" ... ;-) So they should be considered as *XOR*. I could have asked three different questions instead, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
RewriteEngine On
### from example.org/foo/ OR example.org/foo// ----> example.org/foo ####
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(foo)/+?$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /%1 [NC,R=302,L]

### redirect foo.html to foo with showing foo.html content ####
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(foo)\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /%1 [NC,R=302,L]


###redirect from foo/index.html to foo AND foo/bar.html to foo ####
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(foo)/(index|bar)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /%1 [NC,R=302,L]
```

Comment: Thank you! Why *302*?

Comment: But it should be *301* (*Moved Permanently* instead of *Moved Temporarily*).

Comment: Alright! I couldn't test it yet, but I will soon. Thank you!

Comment: @ThreeYearOld, your welcome, if your requirement is same as shown question then it should work because I tested them and they were working fine cheers and happy learning